# How to put specific values, from a function, into a table in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

Good day,
I have a script in python that takes several binary classification methods and models the same set of data.

Having produced the run time (seconds), precision, recall, f-measure and support for the models, I would like to put these details, among other, into a summary table. 
So a table that has the classification method, run time, average precision, average recall, average f-measure and support as one line in a table and then the next line for the next classification method.

How do I go about creating this summary table?

I use the classification_report function to generate the performance metrics.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from sklearn import svm

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=2)#Polynomial Allocation

import time
start = time.time()          
#############################
clf.fit(X_train_selected, y_train)
#############################
run_time = (time.time() - start)         

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_selected)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print('Support Vector Machine - Lasso Shrinkage - Polynomial Kernel')
#print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print(run_time,' seconds for SVM- Lasso Shrinkage - Polynomial Kernel')
```

I would like to put values, highlighted in yellow, below as a single line in table with multiple classification methods.

[image]

Comment: Could you add relevant code and an example output dataframe?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I updated the question as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `output_dict=True` to your `classification_report` call, and then create a pandas dataframe from the dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

output = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, output_dict=True)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output, orient="index")
```

Then you can add columns for the other data you want to save:

```
df["runtime"] = round(run_time, 2)
df["method"] = "SVM - Lasso Shrinkage - Polynomial Kernel"
```

If you want to add more rows to the dataframe from other methods, you can use [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).